AI defense system detects anomaly at edge of solar system
An AI defense system detects an anomaly entering the solar system, runs Monte Carlo simulations to determine the anomaly is likely hostile, engages the defense perimeter, and notifies earth. This all happens in a fraction of a second.
This is a short story on some world-building website similar to SCP Foundation. It was posted as a link in a comment in Hacker News in response to some real-life space event. I read it within the past two years, though the story may have been much older.

Possibly something from qntm's site? It has some similarities to "Valuable Humans In Transit", for example.

That’s a good story, but not it. I searched on qntm for other possibilities but came up empty.

It is possible that this story you are referring to might belong to the Orion's Arm Universe, which is a science fiction based world-building website similar to SCP. This universe often features intelligent defense systems, AIs, and advanced weaponry.
While I'm not familiar with all of the content on the site, one short story comes to mind: "Solar anomaly" M. L. Conymous/ Linus Cohen which might fit:

It contains a weapon fired by an ancient weapons cache entering a
solar system
An AI aboard a starship identifies the anomaly as a
threat, and notifies the system's inhabitants

The particular story you mentioned might not fit perfectly if the AI is a spaceship engineer rather than a defense system and the system in question is not Sol.

As Destiny turned away from Gialfa, Taxon Seven—s warning swept from
her, a pulse of emissions describing a Code Red threat to the system.
All ships in system were told to evacuate at once. For some ships
receiving the warning, that effort might have been in vain; by the
time the message reached the ships orbiting Tykon, they would have but
ten minutes before the first blast hit.

If the specific story you recall isn't it, perhaps one of the other stories or articles might fit. Beware that it is easy getting lost in the maze.
